# Can I restore removed files in cloud9-ide?

Tags: backup, restore, cloud9-ide

Good evening,

I discovered [cloud9-ide](https://c9.io) a few weeks ago and I find its possibilities for workig in a projetc team incredible.

When I came up with it at our teammeating I mentioned it, and my collegue asked the question
"**It is pretty nice that you can see what was changed and that you can reverse it, but does this can also restore deleted files?**"

I stood there, awkwarldy, and had to admit that I have no idea if this works and if so, how?

Can someone help me out? Is restoring deleted file possible? This would be a HUGE contra, if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To restore a deleted file simply recreate it then look at the revision history. All previous versions will be there.

Comment: Please note: [The File Revision History pane is not available for files in an AWS Cloud9 SSH development environment.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/file-revisions.html)